# Keep application in background in response to an Intent

Tags: android, background, timeout, android-intent

My Android application has an inactivity timeout. On a timeout, I return the user to the 'Sign In' screen which is (always) in the back stack. My SignIn class has `android:launchMode="singleTop"` set so the instance running in the backstack is always reused.

I start this intent on timeout:

```
Intent inactivityTimeout = new Intent(this, SignIn.class);
inactivityTimeout.putExtra(INTENT_EXTRA_INACTIVITY_TIMEOUT, true);
int flags = inactivityTimeout.getFlags();
flags = flags|FLAG_FROM_BACKGROUND|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP;
inactivityTimeout.setFlags(flags);
```

When the SignIn screen starts up, it checks for the `INTENT_EXTRA_INACTIVITY_TIMEOUT` Intent extra. If found, it shows a "You've been Signed Out" dialog. This is all working correctly.

Now I'll get to the problem: Since it's based on a timer, this Intent can be fired off regardless of if my application is in the foreground or background. This is desired as I wouldn't want the app to stay logged in indefinitely just because it's in the background.

However, when the application is in the background and the timer expires, this inactivityTimeout Intent is fired off and the application is *brought back to the foreground*. It's not urgent to alert the user *right now* that they've been timed out, so I'd prefer the app stays in the background so as to not interrupt the current action.

I tried adding the `FLAG_FROM_BACKGROUND` flag to my Intent but the application is still brought to the foreground. I'm not certain what else to try, or if this is a problem that I should be addressing in my Intent or in my receiving activity.

Can anyone suggest a way to implement this in my Intent (or in the responding activity?). Or am I missing something conceptual here? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no need to proactively revoke credentials due to age. After all, the process may well terminate before the user ever tries to reuse those credentials.

Each activity needs to check to see if the user has valid credentials. In that check, you also check for age, and simply fail the credential check if the credentials are correct but too old. And, on a failed credential check, you bring up your login activity.

This allows you to dump the timer.

Comment: Thanks Mark! This is very helpful. However, I stupidly left out at least a couple details: first, the inactivity timeout is local and is reset any time the user performs any action (I use onUserInteraction() for this). Second, when timeout occurs while the app is in the foreground, I'd like the Intent to fire without any further user interaction. That's where the timer comes in handy (I reset it when activities change and onUserInteraction() - if it runs down to 0 it'll launch the Intent).

Comment: Anyway, as you suggest I can update a value on the credentials (such as `timeOfLastAction`) to track the most recent user action. Still, I'd have to periodically check if these credentials are valid (i.e. not old enough to be trigger timeout) and show the dialog if they have become invalid since the last check. In order to implement this functionality I'd have to keep the timer, right?

Comment: @Jordan: Just check to see if the credentials are good/stale in `onResume()`, since you already are updating your `timeOfLastAction` there. If you're really paranoid, also check the credentials in places like `onPrepareOptionsMenu()`.

Answer (score 2):

You can have a global static variable to check if the application is on foreground:

```
public static boolean isForeground = false;
```

On every activity onPause set the variable false
On every activity onResume set the variable true

This way you know if the app is on foreground or not.

When the timeout is reached, if the activity is in foreground, fire the intent.
If it's not, set a global static variable true. This variable will be check on every onResume and if its true it will fire the timeout intent (this way it will be fired when you resume the app).

```
public static boolean hasTimeout = false;
```

This will be easier if you have a BaseActivity where you implement this, that is extended by all other activities.

Comment: I was about to post almost the same when your answer showed up. The only difference is that I was thinking a flag in SharedPreferences instead of the static field.